# Como pausar e continuar apos um evento um For?

Tags: javascript, html, for

to com esse codigo aqui:

```js
function aparecer(){
  const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];
    for (let i=0; i < array1.length;i++){
      const lugar = document.getElementById('local');
     
     const ul = document.createElement('UL');
     const valor = document.createTextNode(array1[i])
      ul.appendChild(valor);
      
      lugar.appendChild(ul)
      break
    
      } 
    
}

function desaparecer(){
 document.getElementById('local').innerHTML= '';
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button onClick='aparecer()'> Aparecer </button>
  
  <button onClick='desaparecer()'> Desaparecer </button>
  
  <div id='local'> </div>
  
</html>
```

E eu quero que a cada clique, apareça apenas 3 numeros. Exemplo: Cliquei em `aparecer`, ai aparece: 1,2,3 cliquei novamente, aparece 4,5,6 cliquei de novo, 7,8,9 e logo apos clicar novamente aparecer so o 10.

Sempre criando um novo UL, e nao substituindo o atual.

Como faço isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var current  = 0;
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];

function aparecer(){
 //verifica se o current é maior do que o array
 if ( (array1.length - 1) < current ) {
  alert("oi");
  //isso deveria parar a função
  return false;
 }
 for (var i= current; i <= (current + 2); i++){
  const lugar = document.getElementById('local');

  const ul    = document.createElement('UL');
  const valor = document.createTextNode(array1[i])
  ul.appendChild(valor);

  lugar.appendChild(ul);

 } 
 current = i;
}

function desaparecer(){
 current = 0;
 document.getElementById('local').innerHTML= '';
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button onClick='aparecer()'> Aparecer </button>
  
  <button onClick='desaparecer()'> Desaparecer </button>
  
  <div id='local'> </div>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito, sobre a parada, tentou usar `break;` pra parar e `continue;` pra disparar de onde parou?

Comment: @MarceloRafael Otimo Marcelo, muito obrigado, mas uma duvida, caso eu queira mudar os numeros alterando-os?

Exemplo:
Clicar e aparecer: 1,2,3
Clicar novamente e aparecer: 4,5,6 no lugar do 1,2,3, no caso, substituindo o 1,2,3 por 4,5,6

Comment: é só voce limpar o container com `element.innerHTML = ''`